# Android Studio: The device may not have sufficient computing power for encoding display contents

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to connect my physical device to Android Studio on Mac, device mirroring is not working. I am getting this error:

[image]

Someone reported [the error here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/260517780?pli=1). But, it is for windows. I am using MAC. Anyone knows how to fix this on MAC?

Android Studio Version:

Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1
Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11076708, built on November 9, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314 aarch64

Answer (score -1):

Just check your android version you have chosen on your Android studio. Keep it as per your device's.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).